# Login to Admin in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-admin

I'd appreciate help with a custom user modul. I set it up analog to this example in the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). I have the following problems:

1. Login to the admin interface does not work. The login page shows up, but does not accept my credentials after creating an user with ./manage createsuperuser in the shell.
2. When creating a superuser, it saves initially the password in cleartext. I had a look in the database and found the password in clear text. I guess this comes from create_superuser() where user.set_password() is not used but password=password (as in the example from django docs, so why would they do that?). I changed it in the shell and then it is encrypted. Login still doesnt work tho.

My Code is as following:
authentication/models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        **kwargs
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
    user = self.model(
        email,
        password=password,
        **kwargs
    )
    user.is_admin=True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

and

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
# use this for auth and sessions
# REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

session = models.ForeignKey(
    'sessions.Session',
    verbose_name='Session',
    blank=True, null=True,
)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
#password = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput()) #render_value=False
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
signed_up_since = models.DateTimeField('Signed up since', default=timezone.now())
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = UserManager()
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def get_full_name(self):
    return self.email

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.email

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    return self.is_admin
```

I edited the settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "authentication.MyUser"
```

I dont use a custom session backend or authentication backends, did the migrations, sqlmigrations etc. Shell gives me this:

```
>>> user.is_staff
True
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a user using `self.model()` in your `create_user` method. This leads to the password being saved as plain text.

You should use the `create_user` method, as in the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). This will hash the password correctly.

```
def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        **kwargs
    )
```